# WPF TreeView with CheckBox - How to Get the list of Checked?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview

I have implemented TreeView with Checkboxes from [here](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/treeview-with-checkbox-in-wpf-using-csharp.aspx)
I shows perfectly well. Now I am wondering to get list of selected/checked items from the tree. I believe I need to code a recursive method. But the author has set the recursive method `GetTree()` to be Static and I can't get any clue to start the recursion. 
Similar article is also found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView?fid=1524861&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=51#xx0xx), I found in a way for my problem overe there also, but couldn't get any thing helpful.

I am attaching whole code here for your reference :

```
    public class TreeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TreeViewModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<TreeViewModel>();
    }

    #region Properties

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<TreeViewModel> Children { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInitiallySelected { get; private set; }

    bool? _isChecked = false;
    TreeViewModel _parent;

    #region IsChecked

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { SetIsChecked(value, true, true); }
    }

    void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
    {
        if (value == _isChecked) return;

        _isChecked = value;

        if (updateChildren && _isChecked.HasValue) Children.ForEach(c => c.SetIsChecked(_isChecked, true, false));

        if (updateParent && _parent != null) _parent.VerifyCheckedState();

        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
    }

    void VerifyCheckedState()
    {
        bool? state = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; ++i)
        {
            bool? current = Children[i].IsChecked;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                state = current;
            }
            else if (state != current)
            {
                state = null;
                break;
            }
        }

        SetIsChecked(state, false, true);
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

    void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (TreeViewModel child in Children)
        {
            child._parent = this;
            child.Initialize();
        }
    }

    public static List<TreeViewModel> setTree(TreeViewModel tree)
    {
        List<TreeViewModel> treeView = new List<TreeViewModel>();
        treeView.Add(tree);
        tree.Initialize();

        return treeView;
    }

    public static List<TreeViewModel> SetTree(string topLevelName)
    {
        List<TreeViewModel> treeView = new List<TreeViewModel>();
        TreeViewModel tv = new TreeViewModel(topLevelName);

        treeView.Add(tv);

        //Perform recursive method to build treeview 

        #region Test Data
        //Doing this below for this example, you should do it dynamically 
        //***************************************************
        TreeViewModel tvChild4 = new TreeViewModel("Child4");

        tv.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("Child1"));
        tv.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("Child2"));
        tv.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("Child3"));
        tv.Children.Add(tvChild4);
        tv.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("Child5"));

        TreeViewModel grtGrdChild2 = (new TreeViewModel("GrandChild4-2"));

        tvChild4.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("GrandChild4-1"));
        tvChild4.Children.Add(grtGrdChild2);
        tvChild4.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("GrandChild4-3"));

        grtGrdChild2.Children.Add(new TreeViewModel("GreatGrandChild4-2-1"));
        //***************************************************
        #endregion

        tv.Initialize();

        return treeView;
    }

    public static List<string> GetTree()
    {
        List<string> selected = new List<string>();

        //select = recursive method to check each tree view item for selection (if required)

        return selected;

        //***********************************************************
        //From your window capture selected your treeview control like:   TreeViewModel root = (TreeViewModel)TreeViewControl.Items[0];
        //                                                                List<string> selected = new List<string>(TreeViewModel.GetTree());
        //***********************************************************
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

I couldn't find appropriate to se the tree dynamically from my code using `SetTree(string topLevelName)` method, hence I added `setTree(TreeViewModel tree)` method to suit my needs.

Can anyone please help me to implement GetTree() method to get list of items that is checked. If an item of the tree is selected, the TreeViewModel's IsChecked property is set to true. So IsChecked can be used to find if the item is selected r not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all checked node in your tree **below and including** a certain node, call the following **GetCheckedItems** method on that node:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> GetCheckedItems(TreeViewModel node)
{
    var checkedItems = new List<TreeViewModel>();

    ProcessNode(node, checkedItems);

    return checkedItems;
}    

private void ProcessNode(TreeViewModel node, IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> checkedItems)
{
    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
        if (child.IsChecked)
            checkedItems.Add(child);

        ProcessNode(child, checkedItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes with your code I could get the list od selected items in the tree. I just had to change IEnumerable to List, as IEnumerable doesn't support Add method directly. Thanks once again.

Comment: Could you elaborate bit on your solution. What is a node reference to here.

in my main window how to get the list of all the items that are checked.

Comment: @RaghulanGowthaman - Your question is very vague. The key to the solution here is that each item in the treeview has an associated `TreeViewModel` instance behind it. Using this, we can run the `GetCheckedItems` method on the **topmost** item of the tree.

Comment: Its just i wasnt sure what was that node. I found it.

Comment: Hello Tvd,can your share your code..i have stuck in same problem