# Treeview Model and Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm creating a Treeview using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800310/wpf-treeview-with-checkbox-how-to-get-the-list-of-checked)

What I can't seem to figure out is how to set the Cursor as Wait while it's going through all of the TreeNodes during the VerifyCheckedState processing.   Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could extend this answer a bit, but there's really not too much to say... try using the [`Mouse.SetCursor` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.setcursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the `Wait` cursor:

```
Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Wait);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to make it all difficult and stuff. :D  Thanks again.

Comment: Most new WPF developers do... it's all part of the learning process.